# How to send ethers to specific address based on solidity contract but not web3py?

Tags: transactions, security, web3.py, payable

I have written a solidity code, running it on Remix and I use ganache and web3py library to interact with it.

My code is something like this:

```
contract simplePayment{
    
    function sendPayment(address payable _reciver) payable public {
        _reciver.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Now, when I use Remix IDE and make a transaction everything is fine. I am able to transfer Ethers to the intended address.

When running this following code (using web3py)
`contractInstance.functions.sendPayment(_receiverAddress).transact({'from':_senderAddress,'value': 1000000000000000000}`
Ethere are getting transferred to `_receiverAddress`

But when running code
`contractInstance.functions.sendPayment(_receiverAddress).transact({'from':_senderAddress,'to':_someOtherAddress,'value': 1000000000000000000}`
 Here the Ethers are getting transferred to `_someOtherAddress`.

How can I resolve this issue from a security perspective in solidity? I know how to use modifiers but do we have some of this equivalent like `msg.sender` for the receiver?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `to` parameter when interacting with a contract. `to` has to be the contract address.

Comment: @Ismael - Thank you for the comment, but if making an application., Isn't it a security issue?

Comment: Perhaps it is a bad api design, but it is something very basic about how Ethereum transactions work that a developer should be aware of.